# using getElementsByName to validate radio button

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button, validation, radio-group

I'm attempting to validate whether a group of radio buttons is checked in order o validate a form.

```
function formValidator() {
    var triedIt = document.getElementsByName('tried');
    if(radioChecked(triedIt, "Please select") {
        return true;
    }
    return false;   
}

function radioChecked(elem, helperMsg) {
    if(document.myform.tried.checked == 1) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

This returns the alert, but for some reason the form gets processed anyway. I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong... any help would be appreciated.

If you're wondering why I don't just use jquery etc... its unfortunately not an option. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo but you're missing a closing `}` for your first function.

Comment: not related to your problem but `document.myform.tried.checked` should actually be `elem.checked`.

Comment: Hey, i've update the code as per your suggestions but it still seems to just go ahead and process the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's happening because `document.getElementsByName('tried')` returns array of elements. So, when you call `elem.focus()` it will throw error (because array haven't method focus) and `js` stops execution.

Comment: perfect, thank you! works a charm. very useful information ;)

Comment: ya you r rht i skipped  this part

Answer (score 1):

```
function formValidator(){
var triedIt = document.getElementsByName('tried');
if(radioChecked(triedIt, "Please select")){
return true;
}
return false;   
}

function radioChecked(elem, helperMsg){
if(document.myform.tried.checked == 1) {
    return true;
}else{
    alert(helperMsg);
    elem.focus();
    return false;
}
}
```

try this i think you skipped one closing bracket ) `in if(radioChecked(triedIt, "Please select"))` that`s why its happening

Comment: Hi, thanks. This was actually a typo on my part, I did include the bracket in my code. Any other ideas?

Comment: other things looking rht can you able to update your html end too